# Difference between Free Shipping field options in Cart Price Rule

Tags: magento2.3, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping

I have to apply free shipping over 1000. For this, I'm creating catalog price rule according to this but it's not working.

In conditions, I have set Subtotal greater than 999.

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-setup-free-shipping-promotion-in-magento-2.html

But when I have changed Free shipping option to For matching items only then it's working.

I'm not understanding what is an issue. Can anyone please explain the difference between **For matching items only** and **For shipment with matching items **?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the difference between For matching items only and For shipment with matching items.

**For matching items only:** Free shipping is available only for specific items in the cart that match the rule.

**For shipment with matching items:** Free shipping is available for the entire cart when a coupon that is based on the rule is used.

Comment: I have to apply for entire cart but not working.

Comment: I'm not using coupon

Comment: For your case, We need to use 2nd option, if any item is matching to the rule in the cart then the free shipping will be applied to the cart.
If we select the first option then it'll only make free shipping for the matching items in the created rule.

Comment: Why matching item? I have to apply free shipping for all products if subtotal is 1000 or more.

Comment: the subtotal of the all items in the cart should be 1000.